# Loading a different view controller after app has already launched

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am a bit new to Xcode.

I have a question about loading up a different once the app has already launched. I've already looked at past questions such as mine and seen that the answer to this in the `appdelegate.m` file, specifically the `didFinishWithLaunchingOptions` method.

However, the code that answers have provided have proven no remedy for me, because I'm using a `storyboard` and as of Xcode 5, the `initwithnib` method can no longer be used.

If my question isn't very clear to you, my code in the `appdelegate.m` is shown below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        NSLog(@"not first launch");
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"  bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        self.initialViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"InitialViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.InitialViewController;
        NSLog(@"first launch");
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:10.0/255.0 blue:10.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:20.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];

UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

return YES;
}
```

I'm facing errors in the code, as shown here:
[image]

So, pretty much my problem is I'm trying to implement this block of code in my method in my `appdelegate.m`, but I'm facing some errors and I don't know why they are occuring.

Here is also a picture of my two view controllers that I would like for them to be the initial[image] view and the view after the app is already loaded once:

If it provides any help:

- The first view controller is a `UIViewController`

  - It is called `ViewController` (in the identities inspector the custom class is named "`Viewcontroller`")
  - I have implemented `ViewController.h` and .m files for this class.
- The second view controller is also a  UIViewController

  - It is called `SWRevealViewController` (in the identities inspector the custom class is named "`SWRevealViewController`")
  - I have implemented `SWRevealViewController.h` and .m files for this class as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the restorationIdentifier, it's right above the Storyboard identifier and it's a UIViewController property.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];
MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];
 self.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

[image]

Comment: @achievelimitless both answers are correct to my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @iDev just one more question. So the string @"<controller id>", do I put my storyboard id or my restoration id?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    CustomVC *rootController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
    }
else{    
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
    CustomVC *rootController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
    }
```

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: I am not trying to be mean, your answer is perfectly acceptable as well, I just am confused what you did with your condition for your if statement. If I choose to use this, does this mean I have to replace by condition for my if statement?

Comment: the 'code if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])'

Comment: I have tried to give you generic code for a universal app. My if condition checks if the device is iPad or iPhone. You don't need to replace your condition here. for iPhone IF condition executes, & for iPad ELSE one. Atleast you can up vote the answers Yaar … ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try and implement your code and see if it works. The only reason reason I couldn't upvote was because I didn't have 15 reputation... However now that I have it, I can upvote ;)